# Заполнение массива по нажатию кнопки

Tags: java, массивы

У меня есть форма на  которой 300 `textfield` и кнопка

```
`public static int i,j,k,l,m,n,z,f;
public static JLabel[] lbl = new JLabel[21];
public static JLabel[] lbl1 = new JLabel[16];
public static JTextField[][] tf1 = new JTextField[20][15];
public static int [][] qw = new int[20][15];
public static Random rand = new Random();
public static void main(String[] args) {
JFrame fr1 = new JFrame("Массив");
JPanel pn1 = new JPanel();
fr1.setSize(600,400); fr1.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
fr1.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
pn1.setLayout(null); fr1.add(pn1);  //fr1.setContentPane(pn1);  //
for(i=0;i<20;i++){
for(j=0;j<15;j++){
    tf1[i][j]=new JTextField();
    tf1[i][j].setBounds(30+i*35,30+j*35,30,25);
    pn1.add(tf1[i][j]);
}
}
for (k=1;k<21;k++){
lbl[k]=new JLabel(""+k);
lbl[k].setBounds(10+k*35,5,30,20);
pn1.add(lbl[k]);
}
for(l=1;l<16;l++){
lbl1[l] = new JLabel(""+l);
lbl1[l].setBounds(5,5+l*35,30,20);
pn1.add(lbl1[l]);
}


JButton btn1 = new JButton("Заполнить");
     pn1.add(btn1); btn1.setBounds(856,250,100,50);
    JTextField tf3 = new JTextField();
    pn1.add(tf3);tf3.setBounds(850,190,40,40);
    JTextField tf4 = new JTextField();
    pn1.add(tf4); tf4.setBounds(910,190,40,40);
    btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (m = 0; m < 20; m++) {
                for (n = 0; n < 15; n++) {
                    qw[m][n] = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
                }
            }
            tf1[i][j].setText("" + qw[m][n]);
        }
    });`
```

Получается, когда я нажимаю на кнопку чтобы заполнился массив и передался в `textfield`, выбивает ошибку, подскажите пожалуйста что не так в `ActionListner` я записал? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Об ошибке мы сами должны догадаться?

Comment: Стектрейс с вас, помощь с нас

Comment: @kff - да, должны сами догадаться. Вы профессионал, или Вы не профессионал?

Comment: @Igor Где уж мне... Обычный быдлокодер-недоучка... ;-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Основная ошибка в том, что Вы пытаетесь в этой строке кода

```
tf1[i][j].setText("" + qw[m][n]);
```

присвоить что-то элементу с непонятными индексами, причём берёте это что-то тоже из массива с непонятными индексами. Нужно `actionPerformed` изменить следующим образом:

```
for (m = 0; m < 20; m++) {
    for (n = 0; n < 15; n++) {
         qw[m][n] = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
         tf1[m][n].setText("" + qw[m][n]);
    }
}
```

В такую ситуацию Вы попали по двум причинам. Первая - Вы даже не попытались разобраться в том, что у Вас написано. Вторая - глобальные переменные. Если бы Вы не объявляли целую кучу переменных на все нужды, а создавали их по мере надобности, этой ошибки бы не произошло и Вы бы получили ошибку уже от компилятора, а не на стадии выполнения. Нужно делать вот так:

```
for (int m = 0; m < 20; m++) {
    for (int n = 0; n < 15; n++) {
         qw[m][n] = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
         tf1[m][n].setText("" + qw[m][n]);
    }
}
```

Счётчики циклов будут существовать только внутри цикла и станут недоступными при выходе из цикла.

P.S. Впрочем, судя по стилю кода и вопросу, мои сентенции будут проигнорированы, поскольку ТС просто нужно сдать лабу и навсегда забыть "эти дурацкие задачки на Жабе!".